# How to update state of another user in Spring Security?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

Suppose a `User` can like `Post`s. when a post is liked, score of the post **author** (another `User`) is incremented. I update the state of the author in database:

```java
post.getAuthor().incrementScore(LIKE_SCORE);
postRepository.save(post); \\ author is also updated
```

but the problem is that if the author is currently logged in, the changes are not reflected to him and he should re-login to see his updated score.

How can I update states of another authenticated user in Spring Security?
**Note that I do not add user to my controller but access principal directly in the template. Am I doing it wrong?**

User entity:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "username")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likers", fetch = EAGER)
    private Set<Post> favorites = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = EAGER)
    private Set<Post> posts = new HashSet<>();

    @NaturalId
    private String username;

    private String password;

    private long score;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    // other overridden methods, getters and setters
}
```

Security configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and().formLogin().usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .successHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                    response.getOutputStream().print(true))

        .failureHandler((request, response, exception) ->
                    response.getOutputStream().print(""))

        .and().logout()
        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                    response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer")))

        .and().cors().disable();
}
```

Thymeleaf template:

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="author">
    <div class="usr-name" th:text="${#authentication.principal.username}"></div>
    <div class="score" th:text="${#authentication.principal.score}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you load the user? Do you save the user in the HTTP session. Show your Spring Security configuration and your controller, which shows the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server sent events(sse) a variation of http streaming . This is to push event to the listeners over http. Springboot has SseEmitter Class to support sse

See the example for sever push with sse https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/sse-emitter.html